# Is metaprogramming being used in real-world c++ software projects?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the use of metaprogramming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468246/whats-the-use-of-metaprogramming)

I know that in C++, there are libraries providing metaprogramming facitlities, like Boost MPL.
But are they really useful in real-world C++ projects ( or just used in rare situations ) ?  ( I have the feeling that metaprogramming code are weird and can generate hard-to-debug compilation errors )

**Thank you.**

Comment: Dup'ish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468246/whats-the-use-of-metaprogramming

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. That question asks why metaprogramming is ever used, while this question is asking for specific cases where TMP is used.

Comment: yes, I want to know examples of real-world projects that are using things like Boost.MPL , but the links are really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's useful. Have you ever used `std::distance` or `std::advance`? They use metaprogramming to do the right thing for bidirectional/random access iterators. (that is, repeated ++ or -- for bidirectional iterators, and += or -= for random access iterators).

TMP is most useful for libraries that need to do one thing for a type argument, or do another thing for a different type argument (i.e. distance/advance).

Are there insane (e.g. Boost::Spirit::Qi) things you can do with metaprogramming? Sure. That's not the average case though.