# undefined reference to `CefURLRequest::Create(CefRefPtr<CefRequest>, CefRefPtr<CefURLRequestClient>)'

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors, chromium-embedded

I am trying to build CEF in Release mode but I get the following linker error:

> AR(target)
>   /home/adminuser/temp/build/linux/Release/obj.target/libcef_dll_wrapper.a
>   LINK(target) /home/adminuser/temp/build/linux/Release/cefclient
>   /home/adminuser/temp/build/linux/Release/ldb.a(ldbJS.o): In function
>   `LdbURLLoader::LoadURL(std::string)': ldbJS.cpp:(.text+0x34e):
>   undefined reference to`CefURLRequest::Create(CefRefPtr,
>   CefRefPtr)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status make: *** [/home/adminuser/temp/build/linux/Release/cefclient]
>   Error 1

I don't get this problem when building the Debug version so I am not quite sure how to resolve it.  I tried various #pragma directives to stop the compiler from optimizing out this method but to no avail.

*** UPDATE ***

When I remove the **-DNDEBUG** flag from **CFLAGS_Release** in the **libcef_dll_wrapper.target.mk** file it will build.  I don't want to do this in the Release build without knowing what I'm doing though.

I am using gcc 4.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out [forcing the LD linker to reanalyze my libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781964/267702) was the solution.  The CEF application already had an elaborate scheme of makefiles that used the **--start-group** and **--end-group** indicators to do this, but the library I previously added was not included with them.  I added it and linked my application without any more problems!