# How to specify imported dependencies of an OBJECT library?

Tags: cmake

I have an `OBJECT` library `objlib` which is linked into the main target `maintarget`. The `objlib` has a dependent library, say, `ZLIB`. If we're using the legacy `<package-name>_*` variables then it's easy:

```
add_library(objlib OBJECT ...)
target_include_directories(objlib ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
add_executable(maintarget $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>)
target_link_libraries(maintarget ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

But I want to use the dependency as an `IMPORTED` library because it's more concise (and the convenient way to create config modules, that is, using `install(EXPORT ...)`, does just that).

The following code does not work because `target_link_libraries` cannot be used with an `OBJECT` library:

```
add_library(objlib OBJECT ...)
target_link_libraries(objlib ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

Linking `ZLIB::ZLIB` to `maintarget` does not work either, `objlib` does not get the include directories:

```
add_library(objlib OBJECT ...)
...
add_executable(maintarget $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>)
target_link_libraries(maintarget ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

Hacking with an intermediate `INTERFACE` library (`objlib-wrapper`) does not work either.

The only thing that works is to query the `IMPORTED` library's properties and regenerate the information normally available in the `<package-name>_*` variables. Which is a nasty workaround.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you recommend instead? There's a library, consists of about ten separate modules, some of them implementing the exported functions/classes, the whole thing compiled both as static and as shared. Put all the sources directly in one single library target?

Comment: If I specify my modules as object libs its easier to specify per-module properties, like each module can have its own set of include dirs, definitions. Their files get automatically separated in the IDE. Of course I could get by without object libs but it's somewhat better than all-sources-in-one-lib in every aspect.

Comment: Yes, using regular lib target for each module would be the best and that was the case until last week. But I needed an easy way to compile them into a single dll. Object lib was the easiest. The alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136184/linking-windows-dll-files-from-static-libraries-using-cmake-without-hand-craftin

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution you were happy with? If so, I'd be very interested in hearing about it.

Comment: [upstream issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14778)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of CMake 3.12, you can now use `target_link_libraries` on object libraries to get usage requirements.

Using 3.12, this approach that you mentioned should work:

```
add_library(objlib OBJECT ...)
target_link_libraries(objlib ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

Comment: this doesn't appear appear to work with other `target_....` commands like `target_include_directories` :-(