# How to retrieve include directory from cmake find_package?

Tags: cmake

I have written a library, built with cmake (currently using version 3.5.1 if that is important), and am now trying to use that library in another project, also built with cmake.

`find_package` finds the library just fine, and creates the exported targets, but unfortunately does not provide the expected `<package>_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable.

Unfortunately I can't post the library, but for example [pugixml](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml) has the same problem:

```sh
mkdir pugi
cd pugi
git clone https://github.com/zeux/pugixml.git .
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/temp ..
make install
```

So far so good. However, trying to `find_package` it:

```
find_package(pugixml REQUIRED)
message(STATUS ${pugixml_FOUND})
message(STATUS ${pugixml_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/temp ..
```

shows that the expected `pugixml_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable is not set:

```
-- 1
--
```

I found that I can retrieve the include directory using a property on the target:

```
get_target_property(INCLUDE_DIRS pugixml INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

```
-- /home/username/temp/include
```

but I have never seen a cmake file do this.

What is the proper method of retrieving the include directory of a package in cmake?

Alternatively, what needs to be done in the package's cmake file such that `<package>_INCLUDE_DIRS` is properly set by `find_package`?

---

Thanks for the tips thus far, I'm getting closer.

The problem turns out to be that I am creating an intermediary object library target, which cannot link to a library. The `target_link_libraries` is only present in the final binary, but that is understandably not enough for compilation of the object library to find the headers.

The question remains: how can I make the object library target aware of the include path of the found package?

---

The marked duplicate unfortunately only solves this problem for relatively new versions of cmake (3.12 or newer). For older versions, `get_target_property` or the associated generator expression seem to be the only way to do this.

Comment: "... but I have never seen a cmake file do this." - This is because extracting if the include directories from the *IMPORTED* library target is **rarely needed**: linking with that target will automatically include these directories for compilation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev linking with the target how? Using `target_link_libraries(myProject pugixml)` still causes `fatal error: pugixml.hpp: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Yes, `target_link_libraries(myProject pugixml)` is a correct way for use IMPORTED library. Probably, the error is caused by other reason. If you want us to help you with the error, we need to see more code (`CMakeLists.txt`) and **exact** error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please see the edit - the problem turns out to be how to add the include path of the found package to an object library target...

Comment: Then you probably want the same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290077/how-to-specify-imported-dependencies-of-an-object-library. Currently it has the only answer which tells that you may use `target_link_libraries` for OBJECT library, but only since CMake 3.12.