# Only link certain symbols from a library

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, ld, libc

I am developing an embedded system with GCC, and would like to only use a few symbols from libc.  For instance, I would like to use the basic memcpy, memmove, memset, strlen, strcpy, etc.  However, I would like to provide my own (smaller) printf function, so I do not want libc to privide printf.  I don't want dynamic allocation in this platform, so I do not want malloc to resolve at all.

Is there a way to tell GCC "only provide these symbols" from libc?

**edit**: To be clear, I am asking if there is a way I can only provide a few specific symbols from a library, not just override a library function with my own implementation.  If the code uses a symbol that is in the library but not specified, the linker should fail with "unresolved symbol".  If another question explains how to do this, I haven't yet seen it.

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391965/what-is-partial-linking-in-gnu-linker) and [another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270984/g-partial-linking-instead-of-archives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace C standard library function ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107259/how-to-replace-c-standard-library-function)

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate, as my question is "can I tell the linker to only use a subset of symbols from a library", not "can I replace this specific function."  The main difference is that in my question, the linker should bail out with an error if a symbol is used that has not been explicitly named from the library.

Answer (score 2):

This should happen "automatically" as long as your libc and linker setup supports it. You haven't told what your platform is, so [here is one where it does work](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2015-q3-update).

So, let's create a silly example using snprintf.

```
/*
 * main.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char l[100];
  snprintf(l, 100, "%s %d\n", argv[0], argc);
  return 0;
}
```

try to compile and link it

```
$ CC=/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
$ CFLAGS="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -Wall -Wextra -O6"
$ LDFLAGS="-nostartfiles -L. -Wl,--gc-sections,-emain"
$ $CC $CFLAGS -c main.c -o main.o
$ $CC $LDFLAGS main.o -o example
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It needs `_sbrk` because newlib `*printf` functions use `malloc` which needs a way to allocate system memory. Let's provide it a dummy one.

```
/* 
 * sbrk.c
 */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void *_sbrk(intptr_t increment) {
  return 0;
}
```

and compile it

```
$ $CC $CFLAGS -c sbrk.c -o sbrk.o
$ $CC $LDFLAGS -Wl,-Map,"sbrk.map" main.o sbrk.o -o with-sbrk
$ /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-size with-sbrk
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  28956    2164      56   31176    79c8 with-sbrk
```

Well, that's the reason you'd like to get rid of `printf` and friends, isn't it? Now, replace `snprintf` with our function

```
/* 
 * replace.c
 */
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...) {
  return strlen(format);
}
```

then compile

```
$ $CC $CFLAGS -c replace.c -o replace.o
$ $CC $LDFLAGS -Wl,-Map,"replace.map" main.o replace.o -o with-replace
$ /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2013q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-size with-sbrk
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    180       0       0     180      b4 with-replace
```

Note that we did not use the `_sbrk` stub at all. As long as you don't provide `_sbrk`, you can be sure that `malloc` is not (can't be) linked and used.

Comment: Thanks for a complete answer.  And good guess, I am using arm-none-eabi- with newlib.  :)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is probably to use a wrapper which defines the symbols and resolves them at runtime using dlfcn:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void* (*memcpy)(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
char* (*strncpy)(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
...

void init_symbols (void) {
    void *handle = dlopen("/lib/libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);

    memcpy = dlsym(handle, "memcpy");
    strncpy = dlsym(handle, "strncpy");
    ...
}
```

and link your binary with `-nostdlib`. This gives you the best control on which symbols to use from which source.

Comment: The question is tagged embedded. There is likely not even a filesystem available (OP is clearly after shrinking the code, which is a clear hint). How do you think dynamically loading a library would work?