# #if DEBUG vs. Conditional("DEBUG")

Tags: c#, debugging, preprocessor, debug-symbols

Which is better to use, and why, on a large project:

```
#if DEBUG
    public void SetPrivateValue(int value)
    { ... }
#endif
```

or

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void SetPrivateValue(int value)
{ ... }
```

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/what-s-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute.aspx for some thoughts on this question.

Comment: you can use this as well: if (Debugger.IsAttached) {...}

Comment: Note for Unity developers: DEBUG means in the editor or in development builds. https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-is-unity-debug-preprocessor-always-defined-yes-by-design.400542/

Comment: For all you folks searching for [Eric Lippert's archived blogpost no longer on msdn: archive.org got you covered](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315164646/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/what-s-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute.aspx)

Comment: Actually, no need for archive.org, @EricLippert moved his blog here: (https://ericlippert.com/2009/09/10/whats-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute/)

Comment: @rold2007: Thanks for the link; I am gradually moving all the old content over but it is not there yet. Also, MSDN did restore my blog archive, which was nice of them.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter: the link above (https://ericlippert.com/2009/09/10/whats-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute/) works for me. The blogs.msdn.com link is broken forever.

Answer (score 650, accepted):

It really depends on what you're going for:

- `#if DEBUG`: The code in here won't even reach the IL on release.
- `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`: This code will reach the IL, however *calls* to the method will be omitted unless DEBUG is set when the caller is compiled.

Personally I use both depending on the situation:

**Conditional("DEBUG") Example:** I use this so that I don't have to go back and edit my code later during release, but during debugging I want to be sure I didn't make any typos. This function checks that I type a property name correctly when trying to use it in my INotifyPropertyChanged stuff.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
protected void VerifyPropertyName(String propertyName)
{
    if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        Debug.Fail(String.Format("Invalid property name. Type: {0}, Name: {1}",
            GetType(), propertyName));
}
```

You really don't want to create a function using `#if DEBUG` unless you are willing to wrap every call to that function with the same `#if DEBUG`:

```
#if DEBUG
    public void DoSomething() { }
#endif

    public void Foo()
    {
#if DEBUG
        DoSomething(); //This works, but looks FUGLY
#endif
    }
```

versus:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void DoSomething() { }

public void Foo()
{
    DoSomething(); //Code compiles and is cleaner, DoSomething always
                   //exists, however this is only called during DEBUG.
}
```

---

**#if DEBUG example:** I use this when trying to setup different bindings for WCF communication.

```
#if DEBUG
        public const String ENDPOINT = "Localhost";
#else
        public const String ENDPOINT = "BasicHttpBinding";
#endif
```

In the first example, the code all exists, but is just ignored unless DEBUG is on. In the second example, the const ENDPOINT is set to "Localhost" or "BasicHttpBinding" depending on if DEBUG is set or not.

---

Update: I am updating this answer to clarify an important and tricky point. If you choose to use the `ConditionalAttribute`, keep in mind that calls are omitted during compilation, and **not runtime**. That is:

MyLibrary.dll

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void A()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
    B();
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void B()
{
    Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

When the library is compiled against release mode (i.e. no DEBUG symbol), it will forever have the call to `B()` from within `A()` omitted, even if a call to `A()` is included because DEBUG is defined in the calling assembly.

Comment: The #if Debug for DoSomething doesn't need to have all the calling statements surrounded by #if DEBUG. you can either 1: just #if DEBUG the inside of DoSomething, or, do a #else with a blank definition of DoSomething. Still your comment helped my understand the difference, but #if DEBUG need not be as ugly as you've demonstrated.

Comment: If you just #if DEBUG the contents, the JIT may still include a call to the function when your code runs in a non-debug build. Using the Conditional attribute means the JIT knows not to even output the callsite when in a non-DEBUG build.

Comment: Conditional doesn't exclude the code. It marks it with metadata. The DEBUG value is matched up at compile time of the CALLING code. This may be inside the assembly that has the marked method or outside of it.

Comment: @JeffYates: I don't see how what you are writing is any different than what I explained.

Comment: @Apeiron if you only have the function content in the #if debug then the function call is still added to the call stack, while this is usually not very important, adding the declaration and the function call to the #if means the compiler behaves as if function doesn't exist, so m-y's method is the more "correct" way of using #if. though both methods produce results that are indistinguishable from each other in normal use

Comment: if anyone's wondering, IL = Intermediate Language - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Comment: It's worth mentioning that parameter evaluation is also omitted if the function call is omitted. This creates an actual functional difference between placing `#if DEBUG` inside the method body and using the attribute.

Comment: I think add `Debugger.IsAttached` to this as third option would be great :) Thanks for your great explination!

Answer (score 69):

Well, it's worth noting that they don't mean the same thing at all.

If the DEBUG symbol isn't defined, then in the first case the `SetPrivateValue` itself won't be called... whereas in the second case it will exist, but any *callers* who are compiled without the DEBUG symbol will have those calls omitted.

If the code and all its callers are in the same assembly this difference is *less* important - but it means that in the first case you *also* need to have `#if DEBUG` around the *calling* code as well.

Personally I'd recommend the second approach - but you do need to keep the difference between them clear in your head.

Comment: +1 for calling code will need to have #if statements as well.  Which means there will be a proliferation of #if statements...

Comment: While the second option (Conditional attribute) is nicer and cleaner in some cases, it may be needed to communicate the fact that a method call would be stripped from the assembly during compilation (by a naming convention, for example).

Answer (score 45):

I'm sure plenty will disagree with me, but having spent time as a build guy constantly hearing "But it works on my machine!", I take the standpoint that you should pretty much never use either. If you really need something for testing and debugging, figure out a way to make that testability seperate from the actual production code.

Abstract the scenarios with mocking in unit tests, make one off versions of things for one off scenarios you want to test, but don't put tests for debug into the code for binaries which you test and write for production release. These debug tests just hide possible bugs from devs so they aren't found until later in the process.

Comment: I totally agree with you Jimmy. If you're using DI and mocking for your tests, why would you need `#if debug` or any similar construct in your code?

Comment: Rather than just for testing, we often do things like setting a default recipient email to ourselves, in debug builds, using `#if DEBUG` so that we do not accidentally spam others while testing a system that must transmit emails as part of the process. Sometimes these are the right tools for the job :)

Comment: I would generally agree with you but if you are in a situation where performance is paramount then you don't want to clutter the code with extraneous logging and user output, but i do 100% agree that they shouldn't ever be used to alter the fundamental behavior

Comment: -1 There's nothing wrong with using either of these. Claiming unit tests and DI somehow replaces a debug enabled build of a product is naive.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Something I sometimes do and consistently found useful is wrapping a validation with a throw inside #if DEBUG and handling the situation without crashing in the #else (optionally with sending us an exception email). For instance, let say a method parameter should not be null, then throwing if it's null inside #if DEBUG but assigning a default value and sending an exception email to us inside the #else.

Comment: One of the comments said using the #if debug so dont send emails to people by accident. this may be a better solution for that situation   

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 18):

This one can be useful as well:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Personally, I don't see how this can be useful compared to the other 2 alternatives. This guarantees that the whole block is compiled, and `Debugger.IsAttached` must be called at runtime even in release builds.

Answer (score 10):

With the first example, `SetPrivateValue` won't exist in the build if `DEBUG` is not defined, with the second example, **calls** to `SetPrivateValue` won't exist in the build if `DEBUG` is not defined.

With the first example, you'll have to wrap any calls to `SetPrivateValue` with `#if DEBUG` as well.

With the second example, the calls to `SetPrivateValue` will be omitted, but be aware that `SetPrivateValue` itself will still be compiled.  This is useful if you're building a library, so an application referencing your library can still use your function (if the condition is met).

If you want to omit the calls and save the space of the callee, you could use a combination of the two techniques:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void SetPrivateValue(int value){
    #if DEBUG
    // method body here
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's presume your code also had an `#else` statement which defined a null stub function, addressing one of Jon Skeet's points. There's a second important distinction between the two.

Suppose the `#if DEBUG` or `Conditional` function exists in a DLL which is referenced by your main project executable. Using the `#if`, the evaluation of the conditional will be performed with regard to the library's compilation settings. Using the `Conditional` attribute, the evaluation of the conditional will be performed with regard to the compilation settings of the invoker.

Answer (score 3):

I have a SOAP WebService extension to log network traffic using a custom `[TraceExtension]`. I use this only for **Debug** builds and omit from **Release** builds. Use the `#if DEBUG` to wrap the `[TraceExtension]` attribute thus removing it from **Release** builds.

```
#if DEBUG
[TraceExtension]
#endif
[System.Web.Service.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute( ... )]
[ more attributes ...]
public DatabaseResponse[] GetDatabaseResponse( ...) 
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("GetDatabaseResponse",new object[] {
          ... parmeters}};
}

#if DEBUG
[TraceExtension]
#endif
public System.IAsyncResult BeginGetDatabaseResponse(...)

#if DEBUG
[TraceExtension]
#endif
public DatabaseResponse[] EndGetDatabaseResponse(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually you would need it in Program.cs where you want to decide to run either Debug on Non-Debug code and that too mostly in Windows Services. So I created a readonly field IsDebugMode and set its value in static constructor as shown below.

```
static class Program
{

    #region Private variable
    static readonly bool IsDebugMode = false;
    #endregion Private variable

    #region Constrcutors
    static Program()
    {
 #if DEBUG
        IsDebugMode = true;
 #endif
    }
    #endregion

    #region Main

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (IsDebugMode)
        {
            MyService myService = new MyService(args);
            myService.OnDebug();             
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase[] services = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService (args) };
            services.Run(args);
        }
    }

    #endregion Main        
}
```