# When to use preprocessor directives in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I think this is a simple question so I assume I'm missing something obvious.  I don't really ever use preprocessor directives but I was looking at someone's code which did and thought it was something I should be familiar with.

So I looked at the msdn example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) it has the code:

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

My two questions are:

- in the example above why do they define DEBUG?  I was under the impression that was set if you compile in debug v. release mode?
- looking at the other example which has `#define MYTEST` and then writes to the console dependent on if it 'defined', but how does this differ from just using a variable?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 20):

I would actually recommend using the Conditional Attribute instead of inline #if statements.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void DeleteTempProcessFiles()
{
}
```

Not only is this cleaner and easier to read since you don't end up having #if, #else within your code. This style is less prone to errors either during normal code edits and well as logic flow errors.

Comment: It should be noted that the method will always be emitted regardless of whether the condition is met.  The attribute only affects whether *calls to this method* will be emitted; this makes it possible to define a method in a library and give it `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` and this will affect compilation against this library.

Comment: Excellent, there's also more information on this over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/3788605/932917

Comment: There is an annoying about of limitations with that Attribute (no constructor (fair) but also the method must be void.

Answer (score 9):

Generally, the optional/conditional compilation symbols will be provided by the build script. It is pretty rare to see `#define`, except for *very* debug code (if you see what I mean).

Re using a variable; I often use such conditions to handle code that must run on different runtimes (mono, cf, silverlight, etc). A variable cannot suffice because the code **cannot be compiled** against the wrong platform (missing types/methods etc).

In the example presented I would probably just have used `Debug.WriteLine`; since this is decorated with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`, all calls to it are automatically removed if `DEBUG` is not defined at build.

Answer (score 5):

> in the example above why do they define DEBUG? I was under the impression that was set if you compile in debug v. release mode?

Probably because it is example code.  It is meant to demonstrate how `#ifdef` and friends work.  I wouldn't expect you to define symbols like that in source files, unless it is for a quick test.

> looking at the other example which has "#define MYTEST" and then writes to the console dependent on if it 'defined', but how does this differ from just using a variable? What am I missing here?

If MYTEST is not defined at compile time, the compiler will not actually emit the code between the `#if` and `#endif` blocks.  Therefore the resultant IL will be smaller.

Also, note that these **are not preprocessor directives** in C#.

Comment: [MSDN calls them "preprocessor directives"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)

Comment: But they are not.  From the same article: *"the compiler does not have a separate preprocessor"*.

Comment: They are probably more accurately called *conditional compilation symbols*. They are similar to those found in C++, but the C# compiler does not have a separate preprocessor. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/09/86979.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you use variable all your code is compiled, when you use preprocessor directives only part of code included in executable/dll.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to give one example where I have used preprocessor directive in my project.

My program creates lot of intermediate files on disk. I used #DEBUG directive to delete those files only if my project is in release mode, otherwise I keep those file so that we can view those intermediate files and determine whats happening inside.

When my app is working on production server, I build project in release mode so those files are deleted after processing is complete.

```
#if (DEBUG==false)
    deleteTempFiles()
#endif
```

Comment: I usually do i#f !DEBUG, I know same thing, but slightly slimmer

Comment: @Neil, Your way is also correct but I prefer DEBUG=false because its more clear to read and understand.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to disable any production code in debug configurations, because it may have side effects you'll never get when debugging (yes, i know it shouldn't, but c'mon we know life, don't we?). For your example I would do it the other way round: If DEBUG is set, copy the temp files elsewhere for inspection before clobbering. Although I admit there are situations when you have to mock things (transaction services etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I have some code which needs a different handling when using the  Mono environment instead of the  CLR - thus I have a Mono directive in some of my modules. I think this is a better example than debug

Comment: If code needs different handling, you should check whether you are running under Mono at runtime and alter behavior accordingly; that way you can still ship one binary to all platforms.  (`if (Type.GetType("System.MonoType") != null) { ... }` is the recommended way to test if you are running on the Mono runtime.  Note that running on Mono does not imply running on Linux; Mono is available for Windows as well as other platforms like OS X.)  However, testing which runtime you are on is usually a bad idea. If you are working around a Mono bug, test if the bug itself is present instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it for a lot of things. Debug messages that I only want in debug builds; clean up temp files; include diagnostic functions or actions.