# asp.net webapi working with environment variables

Tags: c#

I am using `asp.net 4.5`. I am trying to get an `appsetting` variable based on environment. How can I check what environment I am running?

```
    public virtual string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var connString = "";
        //if dev environment
          connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnStringTest"];
        //else if check for prod
         ...

        return connSring;
    }
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use [directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) to check if you're in debug or release or set and check [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c) or possibly [conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222338/when-to-use-preprocessor-directives-in-net).

Comment: [Web config transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) are common practice for updating connection strings based on environment during deployment (if that is what you are looking to do).

Comment: @CalC Actually I'm not. Thanks though.

Comment: @lamelemon This won't work well if I have to enable Debug in production. Is there another way?