# [Conditional ( "SILVERLIGHT" )]

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, conditional-statements, system.diagnostics

WCF Conditional Operations in Service Contract

```
#if SILVERLIGHT // <------------------------------ ( 1 )
// Silverlight Operations
#else // <------------------------------ ( 2 )
// NON Silverlight Operations
#endif
```

**Mark #1** can be converted to

```
[Conditional ( "SILVERLIGHT" )]
```

**How** to convert **Mark #2** ( `ELSE` Condition [ **NON** Silverlight ] )

Comment: I do not think there is a direct counterpart, and frankly in most cases if you are trying to get one physical file to compile for multiple target platforms, then #if is usually your main option (unless you target the portable class library framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) is not the same as a [`C# Preprocessor Directives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(v=vs.71).aspx). So, attempting to replace one with the other is not really appropriate.

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788719/347172

Answer (score 2):

[`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) has some restrictions that `#if` does not have. Namely, the method cannot return anything but void and you cannot provide a negative version.

`#if` simply omits the code, but `Conditional` tells the compiler to noop calls to it.