# Is it possible to use the conditional attribute to create similliar debugger and run-time method?

Tags: c#, conditional-attribute

is it possible to create 2 methods that have the same method-name, passed in values and returns using the conditional attribute and some anti conditional for example

```
[Conditional("Debug")]
    private string StringGenerator()
    {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string guidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
        guidString = guidString.Replace("=", "");
        guidString = guidString.Replace("+", "");
        return guidString;
    }


    [!Conditional("Debug")]// I know using '!' doesn't really work
    private string StringGenerator()
    {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string guidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());

        return guidString;
    }
```

so that you could just call a method and based on whether "Debug" is defined the compiler will choose which method?

Thanks

Comment: Real life example [HtmlAgilityPack/IOLibrary.cs](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/HtmlAgilityPack/IOLibrary.cs) if anybody is interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `#if DEBUG` syntax like so:

```
#if DEBUG
    private string StringGenerator()
    {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string guidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
        guidString = guidString.Replace("=", "");
        guidString = guidString.Replace("+", "");
        return guidString;
    }

#else
    private string StringGenerator()
    {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string guidString = Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());

        return guidString;
    }
#endif
```

However, there are some differences with using this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug) for more details.

Comment: @chuex - Right! Forgot about that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot to even check that

Comment: Would this be advisable on a semi large scale to mock/unit-test a API? (calling method that will either call a api and return its return or debug method return a mock return)

Answer (score 4):

No this is not possible.  The `Conditional` attribute doesn't control whether or not a method is defined in code, it just controls the conditions under which the method call is included in the calling code.

Additionally it's possible for the `Conditional` attribute to be applied multiple times to a method.  Hence there isn't a simply `on / off` decision to be made here.  Consider

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[Conditional("TRACE")]
void Target() { ... }
```

There are 4 combinations here to consider, not just 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple functions/methods with the same name and the same signature.  You can overload a method by changing its signature, though.  For example:

```
Private Function myMethod() As String
    Return "D"
End Function
Private Function myMethod(ByVal myString As String) As String
    Return "D"
End Function
```

Instead trying to create the same exact function, that does two different things, it might be better to pass in a variable and, depending of the value, do two different things.

```
Private Function myFunction(ByVal test As String) As String
     if(test.toUpper()= "QA") then
        'do one thing
     elseif(test.toUpper() = "LOCAL"
        'do another
     else
         'must be Prod
     end if
end Sub
```

Normally what I do is have a key in my web.config file that denotes what Environment i'm using (Local, QA, Prod) and depending on that value, i'd pass a different parameter into my function/method.  Then, when I publish, i change the web config key