# Removing NLog depencency in release mode

Tags: c#, deployment, nlog

I'm developing a small open source library which is also [available](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nuve/) on Nuget with no dependencies. Now I want to use NLog just for debugging purposes in "Debug Mode" but I don't want it to be a dependency when I release new versions on Nuget. What is the best way to do it if this is a reasonable approach at all.

thanks

Comment: Use [#if DEBUG or the Conditional(“DEBUG”) attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug) to stop the code being included in release mode, and a [conditional project reference](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/conditional-project-or-library-reference-in-visual-studio/) to remove the NLog dependency in Release mode.

Comment: I don't think you're able to add or remove project dependencies based on configuration (Release vs Debug). You can use the solution provided above as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Logger.ConditionalTrace("entering method {0}", methodname);
```

etc. Those will be removed in a non-debug build. . See [NLog 4.0 release post](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html). Then you can safely remove the dependency in your NuGet package.