# Test Which folder project is running from in C#

Tags: c#

I have code that tests which folder a project is running from to determine if it is the testing version or production version.  I know there is a way to do this with the difference between debug version and released (which I want to do in the future but I don't know how yet).  So for now, this is a workaround to get me what I need. This code works correctly when I run from Visual Studio but not when my scheduled task runs the compiled version.

```
string projectPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var TestVersion = true;
if (projectPath == @"H:\Automation\RefreshData\RefreshData\bin\Debug" || projectPath == @"\\atlelz1fs03.atalanta.local\USERS\Automation\RefreshData\RefreshData\bin\Debug" || projectPath == @"H:\Automation\RefreshData" || projectPath == @"\\atlelz1fs03.atalanta.local\USERS\Automation\RefreshData")
{
    TestVersion = false;
}
```

Which folder should I be looking at for the compiled version? or is there a better way for me to determine this?

Comment: Why don't you just display `projectPath` so you can see?

Comment: Use `#if DEBUG` instead. [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug)

Comment: *Which folder should I be looking at for the compiled version* well that depends on where you put the compiled version! That's basically why this is a bad idea in a nut shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [precompiler statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

```
#if DEBUG
    var TestVersion = true;
#endif
#if !DEBUG
    var TestVersion = false;
#endif
```

then when in debug mode run with debug selected in visual studio (as normal) when you release this change it to `Release`:

[image]

this will set `TestVersion` to `false` in your released code only. (BTW I have lots of configuration options, just ignore these, you will likely have `Debug` and `Release` only)

This works even better if you use continuous integration to compile your code for you, you can then configure this to do this, so you don't forget.

Comment: Liam how do I define DEBUG?  I just tried this method but I used #else instead and it still came up as TestVersion true.

Comment: DEBUG is a built in variable in the precompiler. It means the DEBUG flag is set on the assembly. It doesn't show up in intelliense, etc. just type it exactly as above

Comment: It is not working for me :( I will put the issue in my original post

Comment: Never Mind I figured it out