# Console App for Debug and Class Library for Release in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, configuration, release

I write class libraries often, and usually add a `Program.cs` so I can switch the output type to "console application" for debugging.

Is there a simple way to set VS up, so that:

- When I select debug configuration, it compiles to a console application
- When I select release configuration it compiles to a class library (and, *if possible*, excludes `Program.cs` from the build)

Comment: Hmm, you can take advantage of conditionals in the .csproj file but pretty unclear how much that would upset the IDE and debugger.  Most programmers take advantage of the built-in unit test runner, recommended.

Comment: @ToshiBoy, Maybe you could think about using conditions with custom code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug