# Transforming App.Config

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I am currently transforming a config file in my project.

Debug config looks like:

```
<appSettings file="C:\MyPath\debug.config"></appSettings>
```

Release looks like this:

```
<appSettings  file="C:\MyPath\release.config"></appSettings>
```

My goal is to switch the file location depending on build profile.

I cannot find a way to transform the file value in the release version.

Reference to similar solution or documentation would be awesome.

Comment: I guess you mean Release looks like this: `<appSettings file="C:\MyPath\release.config"></appSettings>`, the xdt attributes should only be available in App.Config

Comment: Yeah! thanks for that. Updating the question.

Comment: Transforming? How? XDT transform? Doesn't this only work on web.config? How does it work on app.config? Are you using a product that you failed to mention (such as slowcheetah)?

Comment: Im pretty sure it works on web.config and app.config as well. This is why I mentioned config file

Comment: Maybe something changed since I last did this. Packages like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform) appear to support my proposition... I might be wrong.

Comment: There are better different solutions for debug-release config transition. I think this question may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug

Comment: @Spender: you can find some info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx)

Comment: @Ahmet
Thanks for this. But my codes works the same for every build profile I have. Only my configuration changes. And I believe its easier to maintain to store all configuration in the config file instead of hard coding them or something. Let me know if i misunderstood your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how its done:

I had to use `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(file)"` in the App.Release.config

Like this:

```
<appSettings  file="C:\MyPath\release.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(file)"></appSettings>
```

This will change only the file value