# How to replace reserved keywords in c# (similar to c++ macros)?

Tags: c#, c++, macros

I want to write simple macro in c#, to be more clear i just want to save some typing when testing (but want use snippets, cause they don't save space). **Want to replace reserved keywords** with shorter words
Example in c++ (return sum):

```
#define r return
int foo(int i, int c){ r (i + c); }
```

So the point is to save same space and typing, is there something similar in c#?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, try typing "re" and then hit Tab. It'll save you typing (but not space).

Comment: Also i need to save some space ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Macro definitions in Preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709463/c-sharp-macro-definitions-in-preprocessor)

Comment: No it's not possible duplicate this is different question with different needs

Comment: @tonni How is it any different? Just because you talk about `return` and not about `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to save space? All I see is that you are making your code unreadable => not maintainable. As mentioned earlier: to save typing IntelliSense and snippets were invented.

Comment: I already say that for testing (app testing), in this scenario code readable is out of focus.

Comment: If code doesn't need to be readable then the clear implication is that it is auto-generated and not going to be read by a human - in which case you don't care how short it is. But if you tell me that it *is* going to be read by a human, then I'm going to tell you that it should be readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not support macros like C++. Visual Studio on the other hand has snippets

Check that question:

[C# Macro definitions in Preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709463/c-sharp-macro-definitions-in-preprocessor)

Macros in a different sense:

http://alookonthecode.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/macros-in-c.html

A Macro Preprocessor in C#

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10049/A-Macro-Preprocessor-in-C

Comment: Snippet have to be written outside of code .... i want to do it in code with something like dictionary or else

Comment: thnx for effort but this don't change reserved keyword it is something like refactory

Comment: In that case you need to write your own preprosessor. Check that codeproject article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10049/A-Macro-Preprocessor-in-C