# Is there any C# analogue of C++11 emplace/emplace_back functions?

Tags: c#, collections, emplace

Starting in C++11, one can write something like

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct S
{

    S(int x, const std::string& s)
        : x(x)
        , s(s)
    {
    }

    int x;
    std::string s;

};

// ...

std::vector<S> v;

// add new object to the vector v
// only parameters of added object's constructor are passed to the function
v.emplace_back(1, "t");
```

Is there any C# analogue of C++ functions like `emplace` or `emplace_back` for container classes (`System.Collections.Generic.List`)?

**Update:**
In C# similar code might be written as `list.EmplaceBack(1, "t");` instead of `list.Add(new S(1, "t"));`. It would be nice not to remember a class name and write `new ClassName` in such situations every time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: 2 things. It constructs the object directly in place at its intended location in the vector (as opposed to copying or moving a pre-existing object), and it forwards the arguments directly to the object's constructor.

Comment: Aren't all C# objects always dynamically allocated, basically always pointer-held? What would such an emplace functionality bring?

Comment: @Angew For `struct` data types it would be marginally faster. For big `struct` data types it would be probably faster. But `struct` data types shouldn't be big, so it would be a solution looking for a problem :-)

Comment: actually for a list it's the same thing as myList.Add(new S(1,"t"));  edit : from cppReference  Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed through std::allocator_traits::construct, which typically uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container. The arguments args... are forwarded to the constructor as std::forward<Args>(args)....

Comment: @Angew To reduce the code size. With emplace you don't need to write `v.insert(S(1, "t"));` in C++. In C# it might be written like `list.EmplaceBack(1, "t");` instead of `list.Add(new S(1, "t"));`.

Comment: @Boo With hypothetical `EmplaceBack` you won't need to write `new ClassName` every time.

Comment: It would be better if you write `C#` implementation and state what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Boo 1) Class names are usually long enough. 2) You always need to remember it while you are writing construction with `Add` function. 3) It is possible to choose shorter name for such function.

Comment: @Sinatr The question is updated.

Comment: If you feel that it is a valuable feature for C# you can always add a feature request at http://connect.microsoft.com.  However I'd be very, very surprised if it makes it to the final list of implemented features.  There's already a way to do it, very few has complained about having to type the class name in the 17 years of C#'s existence, and it serves no practical purpose in C# (unlike C++).  Plus the amount of design, testing and documentation, likely far outweigh the perceived benefit.  Get used to typing class names...

Comment: In C#9 you can do `new()` when the compiler can determine the type.

Comment: @mhand Could you provide an example of source code using such `new()` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can a bit improve [@Boo variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35986202/2881286) with extenstion.
You can create object instance with [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) so it make solution more generic.

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static void Emplace<S>(this IList<S> list, params object[] parameters)
    {
        list.Add((S)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(S), parameters));
    }
}
```

**Note:** not checked type and count parameters, so if you do something wrong, you get errors just in run-time

Answer (score 6):

In general there is nothing similar in C#, and its need is much less than in C++.

In C# when you have a `List<SomeReferenceType>` what you really have is a `List<ReferenceToSomeType>`, so a list of references, with the size of each element of 4 or 8 bytes (see [How big is an object reference in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800882/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-net)). Copying a reference doesn't cause the underlying object to be duplicated, so it is very fast (you are copying around 4 or 8 bytes, and the processor is optimized for this operation, because that is the size of the native pointer of the processor). So when you `someList.Add(someReference)` what you are doing is adding a reference to your `List<>`.

In C++ when you have a `std::vector<SomeType>` what you have is a vector of `SomeType`, with the size of each element equal to `sizeof(SomeType)`. Inserting a new element in `std::vector<>` will cause the element you are inserting to be duplicated (cloned, copied... choose a verb you like). This is an expensive operation.

Quite often the pattern you use is that you create an object just to insert it into a `std::vector<>`. To optimize this operation in C++11 they added two ways to do it: the `std::vector<>::emplace` method and support by the `std::vector<>` of the move semantic. The difference is that the move semantic must be supported by the `SomeType` type (you need a move constructor with the `noexcept` specifier), while every type supports the `emplace` (that in the end simply used placement constructor).

Comment: It's necessary to reduce code size: with hypothetical `EmplaceBack` you don't need to write `new ClassName` in `Add` statement every time.

Comment: @Constructor: If all it did in C++ was save you a little typing, it wouldn't exist, because that certainly is not one of the motivations for it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Of course, you are right. But it is so good not to write `ClassName` (C++) or `new ClassName` (C#) in such situations every time.

Comment: @Constructor There is at least another reason why in C# it would be less usefull... In C++ if you try to put a `DerivedType` object inside a `std::vector<BaseType>` [very bad things happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), and no one wants these bad things. In C# it is perfectly ok to put a reference to `DerivedType` in a `BaseType` variable/container (and it is a common pattern). So having in a `List<BaseType>` an `Emplace()` that can only build `BaseType` would be less useful.

Comment: @xanatos Yes, you are right. But at least in 95% of cases you add to the list objects of the same type you have specified at the list's declaration, so such function might be useful enough.

Comment: @Constructor Not all the patterns that could be useful are implemented in C#. This would require the support for parameterized `new()` constraints for generic, plus variadic generics (plus some glue between the two). C++ is much more advanced in the "compile time metaprogramming" than C#

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I began to realize that sad thing. Is there any .NET language with metaprogramming capabilities as powerful as such that C++ have?

Comment: @Constructor I do feel very much that you are exchanging what is the side effect (no need to explicitly name the class name) for the real reason (no copy during insertion). C++ is much more verbose than C#. All its meta-programming power often sticks its "ugly" head out and then you have lines of code full of `std::move`, `std::forward` and other esoteric things.

Comment: @xanatos This side effect does a program code mush nicer.
For me it is better to have an ugly way to do something than not to have any one. IMHO, C++ metaprogramming is ugly but C# language restrictions are ugly, too, in this case. I want to avoid code duplication in all its forms.

Comment: Yes, but what if you have a List<struct>? It would still be useful!

Answer (score -1):

in c# you can use extension method to achive what you want

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static void Emplace(this IList<S> list, int x, string s)
    {
        list.Add(new S(x, s));
    }
}
```

then use it like this

```
myList.Emplace(1,"t");
```

Comment: And write such method for all overloads of all constructors of all classes I want to be members of collections? I'm too lazy...

Comment: @Constructor, you can create object instance with reflection so it make solution more generic

Comment: @Grundy How is it possible?

Comment: @Constructor, something like `public static void Emplace<S>(this IList<S> list, params object[] parameters){ list.Add((S)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(S), parameters))}`

Comment: @Grund Thank you. Could you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have following problems:

1. It's longer **to type** by `"new S"`. But `"add"` is shorter than `"emplace"`. Type is added for you by intellisense (simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing `"new "`):

---

[image]

---

2. You are afraid to write a wrong type. Well you can't with `List<T>`. Intellisense will help you to type and compiler will not allow wrong type to be added at compile time anyway.
3. Performance: see [@Xanatos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35986274/1997232).

`list.Add(new S(1, "t"));` is perfectly fine to use.

Conclusion: we don't need `emplace` in `C#`.

Comment: A simple question: why do I need to type anything that can be added by intellicence (a program, not a human)? It is not a programmer's job to do things that can be automated at IDE/compiler level.

Comment: I don't understand you comment. Can you give an example explaining what you mean please? Intellisense is not a human, so it can only offer assistance at certain points (e.g. typing `.` will show list of accessible members of what is to the left). It might be possible to *automate* `emplace` (using [pre-processor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/709463/1997232), e.g. VS extension, not sure here), but I don't see a single valid point why would I want it.

Comment: You wrote: "Type is added for you by intellisense." If intellisense is smart enough to add a type why should I do it myself? It can be simply done at a compiler level.

Comment: I see your point now. I would rather prefer `add` + `new` myself even if there would be `emplace` mechanics. The wrong/boring things are getting constantly addressed (see [`C# 6.0`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)). Would that very minor thing you want ever get into the list? I doubt.