# EmguCV: Emplace one Mat onto another?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

In C++ if you wanted to emplace one mat into another, the code would simply be:

```
clone_img.emplace(out_mat);
```

Now, I know in C# there is no real equivalent to the "emplace" method. If I was working with other data types in a more standard collection, I can find the answer for what I want to do on Google. Working with a cv::Mat is a bit different though, and I can't find anything about that.

There is a Mat.PushBack method, but it doesn't construct the new object in-place within the collection. Or does that not matter?

What is the C#/EmguCV equivalent of this emplacement, and what would be the differences under the hood to be aware of?

Comment: What would be the output of that method in c++? Also, can this answer your question in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35986274/17667233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for what I wanted to do, although it may not exactly answer this above question.

What I wanted to do was to create an empty `Mat`, and then call `Mat.emplace()` to put something else in it.
I found out it was as simple as doing:

```
Mat newMat = old_mat;
```