# How do I do preprocessor text replacement in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make something like the following pseudo-code work:

```
#define IMPORT = [DllImport ("MyDLL")] private static extern;

public class MyClass ... {
    IMPORT void my_function();
    ....
}
```

However, it would seem that #define works quite differently than in C/C++. Is there an equivalent for this in C#?

I know that #define will NOT work this way in C#, but if want to have the same functionality, how would it be done in C#? Are there any language features that allow for this?

Comment: C# has no equivalent.  It's preprocessor is much more limited compared to C/C++.

Comment: From the [C# Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) _Unlike C and C++ directives, you cannot use these directives to create macros._ You'd just have to spell it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709463/c-sharp-macro-definitions-in-preprocessor