# C#: How to shorten MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name inside my code?

Tags: c#, syntax, macros

I'm going to pass the current class name as a parameter to some of the functions inside my codes.

I have many calls like this inside my code:

```
return Ok(new WebServiceResult(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_MINUS_002_INVALID_REQUEST_DATE,
          MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name));
```

The part `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name` is intended to return name of the current class.

How can I shorten this `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name` using C# syntaxes?

I was looking for a thing like macros in C/C++, something such as:

```
#define CLASSNAME MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name
```

but it seems Macros are not supported in C# and [it is not a good practice in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/709469/1080355) if I understood correctly.
However, for making my code clearer and more readable I'm looking for something to replace this snippet and make it shorter.

P.S. I don't want to fetch name of calling class inside the called method itself but I'm looking for a way to shorten my code and make it more clear.

Comment: CallerMemberAttribute has nothing to fetch calling ClassName. It got the name of Calling Method Name but not for the Class Name itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class constant by using `nameof`. The compiler checks that this name exists. Rename refactorings will also change this name inside `nameof`.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private const string ClassName = nameof(MyClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for logging I would consider using [attributes to insert the file-name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-6.0). If you use one file per class, and you probably should, it provide a similar way to discover the source of the log-message. Using these attributes will make the compiler insert the parameters at compile time, making it way faster than using reflection.

Example

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

If must have the actual class name this approach will not be feasable. A possible workaround could be to use a separate static method that inspects the call stack to [find the calling method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method), allowing you to provide a shorter method. Inspecting the call stack will be somewhat slow, but everything involving reflection is somewhat slow. Just remember to mark your helper method as non-inlinable: `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`