# Is it possible to do real addition in preprocessing not only replacement?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I want to do **real addition** (not just a replacement) of two macros and want to use their result in another macro.

for example.

```
#define NUM_1 1
#define NUM_2 2
#define NUM_3 3

#define ADD(X,Y)   ((X)+(Y))

#define CAT_(X,Y)   X##Y   //For two layer of indirection
#define MY(NUMBER)  CAT_(NUM_,NUMBER)
```

now this I want to use some thing like this

```
MY( ADD(NUM_1 , NUM_2 ))
```

or by this way

```
#define RESULT ((NUM_1) + (NUM_2))

MY( RESULT )
```

I'm expecting output as of `MY(RESULT)` or `MY(ADD(NUM_1,NUM_2))` as

```
 NUM_3
```

Is it possible to do in the preprocessing stage? If yes please guide me how I can do.

I'm getting result `NUM_((1)+(2))` which is completely fine according to preprocessor output.

I have framed my problem in simple addition form. Actually, My requirement is to use a result of one complex equation which will make relation to some 1000 macros in form of like `EEPROM_PAGE_10` here `10` is an output of some other equation came by an arithmetic operation on another `#define` macro and this I can't forward to the compiler.

**Note**
This question is not same as [Can I add numbers with the C/C++ preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539549/can-i-add-numbers-with-the-c-c-preprocessor)
because in that post we are replacing with the well-known result,
 for example, they have defined the macro like

```
#define ADD_1_AND_2 3
```

my requirement is different, I want to know that, Is it possible to convert `((2)+(1))` equal to `3` in preprocessing stage. so I can use `3` as `NUM_3` for generating relevant output.

Comment: Stay away from macros looking like functions.

Comment: The compiler will likely do this addition itself.

Comment: You cannot do that... but you might be able to do something way better if you learn template, constexpr and modern C++ in general... but it won't be token like that so we need to know what you are trying to achieve. I don't see how the above macro could be useful if it would works like you want except maybe for code obfuscation...

Comment: @Phil1970 I have modified my post to give some better clarity. please let me know if you need some more info

Comment: No, impossible. You have to use stuff like `#define ADD_1_AND_3 3`, probably generated with a script.

Comment: If this gets reopened, the answer is certainly **yes**: include [Order-PP](https://github.com/polytypic/order-pp) and you can more or less `#define ADD(X, Y) ORDER_PP(8add(X, Y))` then have `ADD(1, 2)` expand to `3`.