# How can I generate a compiler warning only some of the time?

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, c++03

Let's say that roughly every fourth build I want to generate compiler warning, probably using `#warning` or maybe conditionally declaring something like `int x = 3.14;` which ought to generate an overflow warning.

How could I do that, using only the predecessor?

Some of these questions look good, but I can't see how to generate a random number between and 4 or to take the modulus of the large numbers which they generate:

[How can I generate unique values in the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132751/how-can-i-generate-unique-values-in-the-c-preprocessor)

[How to generate a series of random numbers with the C/C++ preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498228/how-to-generate-a-series-of-random-numbers-with-the-c-c-preprocessor)

[Generate a random number using the C Preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355317/generate-a-random-number-using-the-c-preprocessor)

---

[Update] I forgot to say that I am constrained to C++ 2003 :-(

I took the answer from [Generate a random number using the C Preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355317/generate-a-random-number-using-the-c-preprocessor) and just added

```
#if KISS / 4 == 1
#warning Danger, Will Robinson!
#endif
```

but then I get

```
../test/main.cpp:105:5: error: token "=" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

Referring to the line

```
#if KISS / 4 == 1
```

Where `KISS` expands to

`(((((z=36969*(z&65535)+(z>>16))<<16)+((w=18000*(w&65535)+(w>>16))&65535))^(jcong=69069*jcong+1234567))+(jsr=(jsr=(jsr=jsr^(jsr<<17))^(jsr>>13))^(jsr<<5)))`

So, it looks like I need a different solution

Comment: Could you reveal line 105 of `main.cpp`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what the problem is.

The solution you have tried will not work because it is a macro-built
method of generating *C code* that generates a pseudo random number
sequence, for use *in blocks of C code*. The generated code contains
assignments to C variables and for that reason of course is illegal within preprocessor
directives: the preprocessor does not have variables or assignments.

You say you don't know how to take the modulus 4 of a large random number,
using the preprocessor, even assuming you can get one in a preprocessor
directive, and perhaps this difficulty is illustrated by:

```
#if KISS / 4 == 1
```

That is not how to get the modulus 4 of `KISS`: it is equivalent to

```
#if KISS == 4
```

`KISS` modulo 4 is `KISS % 4` and the way to test in a preprocessor
directive if `KISS` is a multiple of 4 is:

```
#if (KISS) % 4 == 0
```

The question title mentions no requirement that the random
value should be generated using the preprocessor only, but within
the post you ask how it can be done using only the preprocessor. If the
objective is simply to generate a compiler warning roughly one time
in 4 then I cannot see why the preprocessor alone should be used to
achieve this and I lean to the view that you have wrongly concluded that it must be
from the fact that the compiler warning must be triggered by a
some preprocessor `#if`-test.

The obvious course is to have your build process - `make` or
whatever - generate a random number with a range of 4 and pass this
value as a commandline macro definition to the compilation of the
source file in which the warning is to be sporadically generated.

You don't say what operating system you are working on, but to
illustrate for ubuntu using `shuf` as the RNG:

**main.cpp**

```
#if (FORTUNE) % 4 == 0
#warning Whoops!
#endif

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Some builds:-

```
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
main.cpp:2:2: warning: #warning Whoops! [-Wcpp]
 #warning Whoops!
  ^
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
main.cpp:2:2: warning: #warning Whoops! [-Wcpp]
 #warning Whoops!
  ^
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
main.cpp:2:2: warning: #warning Whoops! [-Wcpp]
 #warning Whoops!
  ^
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
main.cpp:2:2: warning: #warning Whoops! [-Wcpp]
 #warning Whoops!
  ^
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
$ g++ -DFORTUNE=$(shuf -i 1-4 -n 1) main.cpp
main.cpp:2:2: warning: #warning Whoops! [-Wcpp]
 #warning Whoops!
  ^
```

If you use that `shuf` command then the random value will always be in the range [1-4], so
your test could simply be `#if FORTUNE == 4`, but
the modulo test will allow you to use any other RNG.