# c preprocessor: arithmetic in concatenation

Tags: gcc, concatenation, c-preprocessor

how can I get the preprocessor to do arithmetic in concatenation?
I tried with:

```c
#define DECL_FUNCT3(ch1, ch2) \
        void funct_ ## ch1 ## _and_ ## ch2 ## _(void);

#define DECL_FUNCT2(ch1, ch2) DECL_FUNCT3(ch1, ch2)
#define DECL_FUNCT1(ch1, ch2) DECL_FUNCT2(ch1, ch2)
#define DECL_FUNCT(ch) DECL_FUNCT1(ch, ch+16)

DECL_FUNCT(0)
DECL_FUNCT(1)
```

I'd like to get:

```
void funct_0_and_16_(void);
void funct_1_and_17_(void);
```

but istead I get:

```
$ gcc -E test.c 
[...]
void funct_0_and_0+16_(void);
void funct_1_and_1+16_(void);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  It's not possible.

The C preprocessor does only perform textual replacements.  The only place where the preprocessor is calculating is like in `#if 10 + 20 == 30`, but that line does not perform any replacements.

Comment: Correction: it's not possible to use macro expansion to evaluate expressions (like `ch+16`), but it *is* possible to do arithmetic (like [`BOOST_PP_ADD(ch,16)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4eacf1422e3b3187) (see @chtz 's answer)), because arithmetic can be *implemented* using textual replacements.

Answer (score 4):

If `ch` is between 0 and 240, you can use [`BOOST_PP_ADD`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/add.html) from the [boost preprocessor library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/) for that:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>

#define DECL_FUNCT3(ch1, ch2) \
        void funct_ ## ch1 ## _and_ ## ch2 ## _(void);

#define DECL_FUNCT2(ch1, ch2) DECL_FUNCT3(ch1, ch2)
#define DECL_FUNCT1(ch1, ch2) DECL_FUNCT2(ch1, ch2)
#define DECL_FUNCT(ch) DECL_FUNCT1(ch, BOOST_PP_ADD(ch,16))

DECL_FUNCT(0)
DECL_FUNCT(240)
```

Godbolt demo (uses C++, but should work for C as well):

https://godbolt.org/z/2edrua (this defines empty functions, instead of declaring them to get some visible assembly output).

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for your specific case: Use hexadecimal numbers in names.

Change 2 macros:

```
#define DECL_FUNCT3(ch1, ch2) \
        void funct_0 ## ch1 ## h_and_1 ## ch2 ## h_(void);
...
#define DECL_FUNCT(ch) DECL_FUNCT1(ch, ch)
```

And you get:

```
void funct_00h_and_10h_(void);
void funct_01h_and_11h_(void);
```

There are some limitations:

- The difference between two numbers must be 16.
- It only works for numbers 00h..0fh and 10h..1fh.