# How to generate a pre-processor definition using arithmetic?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, string-literals

I want to dynamically create pre-proccessor literal strings where part of the string is created by some arithmetic, for example: `math(x) x - 0x1234`. The generated definitions would be made by the macro:`get_tex_uniform_name(unit)`, and the results would be the same values as the following numerically ordered definitions:

```cpp
// texture uniform naming
#define TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME       "tex"
#define TEX_UNIFORM_0               TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME"0"  // "tex0" and so on
#define TEX_UNIFORM_1               TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME"1"
#define TEX_UNIFORM_2               TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME"2"
#define TEX_UNIFORM_3               TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME"3"
```

I have tried generating the string from scratch with STRINGIFY (#):

```cpp
#define get_tex_unit_num(unit) unit - GL_TEXTURE0
// create string literal from whatever is put in
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define LITERAL_STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define get_tex_uniform_name(unit) TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME LITERAL_STRINGIFY(get_tex_unit_num(unit))

// issue: result is "texunit - 0x84C0", 0x84C0 being GL_TEXTURE0
```

I have tried token pasting to work with existing definitions:

```cpp
#define get_tex_unit_num(unit) unit - GL_TEXTURE0
#define get_tex_uniform_name(unit) TEX_UNIFORM_ ## get_tex_unit_num(unit)

// error: TEX_UNIFORM_get_tex_unit_num is undefined
```

And have been trying to get some sort of bit masking to work:

```cpp
#define TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME       "tex "

#define get_tex_unit_num(unit) unit - GL_TEXTURE0
#define get_tex_uniform_name(unit) TEX_UNIFORM_BASE_NAME & (0xffffff00 + (char)get_tex_unit_num(unit))

// error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
```

I know that this could be done with functions or by just using the concatenated literal strings as defined in the first example. I am not necessarily looking for a reason why my examples don't work. I am looking for a way to get these strings dynamically, and am having trouble using arithmetic inside macros to create a string literal.

Comment: I feel like it'll take an entire answer to explain exactly how you need to clarify your question, before it can be answered.  A *macro* cannot reduce an *expression* (aka, `0xFFFFFF00-get_tex_unit_num(unit))`) to a number.  *The preprocessor* can do this, however (it requires using conditional directives, which you can't just "call" in a macro).  Macros *can* do math, but that requires macro-friendly forms like `LOGAND((F,F,F,F,F,F,0,0),SUB((3),GL_TEXTURE0))` where hex numbers are re-represented as `(x,y,z)` (and basically you *implement* math, so it's a lot of work)...

Comment: ...so if you want an actual, working implementation, it's critical that your question is as nit picky as possible.  So... basically, you can't *evaluate expressions* using *macros*; but, do you want to *evaluate expressions* using the *preprocessor*, or *do arithmetic* using *macros*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the C preprocessor perform integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560357/can-the-c-preprocessor-perform-integer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code sample should work, so it is not necessary to paste string literals together in the preprocessor. It is also not possible.

It is not possible because `##` pastes together two preprocessing tokens, and the result must be a valid preprocessing token. A preprocessing token is a header name, identifier, preprocessing number, character constant, string literal, punctuator, or single non-white-space character. You cannot paste together two string literals and remove the two quote marks that end up between them. However, it is usually unnecessary to paste them together; simply letting them expand next to each other suffices because adjacent string literals are concatenated.

Your first code sample, which generates results like `"tex" "0"` is fine. After preprocessing and before analysis and translation (compilation), adjacent string literals are converted to a single concatenated string literal. So there will not be any problems of precedence or other syntax and semantics.

Comment: Note: This address only the concatenation of string literals. If there is a problem expanding `unit` to a desired string literal, that is not addressed—that problem is not explained clearly in the question.

Comment: TY for the answer. Made some updates to the original post. I am not so much looking for a reason why my examples don't work, but rather I am having trouble using arithmetic inside macros to create a string literal.

Comment: @ichster: You won't be able to use arithmetic inside the macros — the preprocessor does text substitution, not arithmetic.  (It does arithmetic in `#if` and `#elif` conditions, but not otherwise.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're confusing evaluating constant expressions with [doing arithmetic](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5233d485a50787c3).

Comment: @HWalters — hmmm; I regard constant expressions as arithmetic (at least when there are arithmetic operators involved — that's a subset of the possibilities for expressions that can be evaluated by the preprocessor.  But I was commenting and giving a useful succinct abbreviated term for what goes on, not giving a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to wrap up this question for future viewers by referencing a question that already answers this question:
[Can the C preprocessor perform integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560357/can-the-c-preprocessor-perform-integer-arithmetic)

In short, the pre-processor can do arithmetic if it is used in when evaluating constant conditions:

```cpp
#if 1 + 2 == 5
#endif
#else
#endif
```

But since you can't combine a macro with this you can't make make string literal definitions before compiling.

Comment: "But since you can't combine a macro with this" ...[why not](https://repl.it/repls/PeachpuffGrayAutomatedinformationsystem)?  (in the repl run (and feel free to examine) main.sh; this is simply a hex version of [boost slots](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/slot.html); and is what I mean by "evaluating expressions using the preprocessor" to solve this problem).