# C Preprocessor output int at Build

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

i want to see output of Preprocessor calculating. Only with strings it works so:

```
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

#define BEGIN "test"

#pragma message ".text= " XSTR(BEGIN)
```

when i set BEGIN to 32/2 the output is: #pragma message: .text= 32/2.

What can i make to solve this? I don´t won´t solutions like this to search in the .lss file:

```
uint16_t x = BEGIN;
PORTB = x>>8;
PORTA = x;
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you *expect* the output to be when you define `BEGIN` to `32/2`?

Comment: And what's an ".lss file"?

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: The C preprocessor will only calculate things inside `#if` conditions. You won't get it to calculate and print something (let's ignore abominations like BOOST_PP). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560357/can-the-c-preprocessor-perform-integer-arithmetic

Comment: @JohnBollinger an .lss file is the Assembler Output file generated from AVR-GCC. The Value 32/2 is only an example. Later this calculate the .text section.

Comment: Do not use double quote when defining BEGIN : #define BEGIN 32/2

Comment: @PtitXav i don´t used double quote for calculations. Only for Strings

Comment: What preprocessor do you use ? With clang I get : #pragma message(“.text= 32/2”)

Comment: Compiler Version = 5.4.0, Preprocessor i dont know. I use the build in from Atmel Studio 7. Does it work for you? I don´t found a way to solve it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can i make to solve this?

You have to implement math operations in the preprocessor. For example:

```
#define _div_1_over_1  1
#define _div_2_over_1  2
#define _div_3_over_1  3
// etc...
#define _div_30_over_2  15
#define _div_31_over_2  15
#define _div_32_over_2  16
// etc...
// etc. for every possible a_over_b combinations, many many 1000 lines
#define DIV(a, b)  _div_##a##_over_##b
```

After that, you finally can:

```
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

#define BEGIN DIV(32, 2)

#pragma message ".text= " XSTR(BEGIN)
```

Let's say this is one way of implementing division in preprocessor. For other solutions, see [BOOST_PP_DIV](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) and [P99_DIV](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/p99/p99-html/group__preprocessor__arithmetic_ga6740ff272bb7153d33a60f66fcda7166.html#ga6740ff272bb7153d33a60f66fcda7166) from p99 library.

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor just performs text replacement(s).

The first opportunity to see folded constants is in the tree dumps with `-fdump-tree-all` and then inspect the `*.t<nnn>` dumps.

To get the asm output from the compiler proper, try `-safe-temps -fverbose-asm` which inserts C source intermingled as asm comments in the `*.s` file.