# C++ macro time arithmetic

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm working on a wgl loader and typedef'd each openGL function that I use like this:

```
/*Let's say I'm defining n functions*/ 
typedef return_t (*f1)(params)
f1 _glFunc1;
#define glFunc1(params) _glFunc1(params)
...
typedef return_t (*fn)(params)
fn _glFuncn;
#define glFuncn(params) _glFuncn(params)
```

Then to get the definitions of these functions I have to use wglGetProcAddress or GetProcAddress and then cast the result to f1, f2 ...
I tried to automate the casting with this macro:

```
#define GetFuncDef(glFunc) _##glFunc = (f##(__LINE__ - startingLineNumber + 1))GetProcAddress(#glFunc)
```

Where `startingLineNumber` is the first line that I use this macro in(in my case it's 22),
but the preprocessor does not compute `__LINE__ - startingLineNumber`.

Is there some way to force it to do so?

EDIT:
`startingLineNumber` isn't a variable, macro etc. It's written out as a literal number in my code. like this:
`#define GetFuncDef(glFunc) _##glFunc = (f##(__LINE__ - 22 + 1))GetProcAddress(#glFunc)`, where 22 would be `startingLineNumber`

Comment: What is `startingLineNumber`? Could you give an example?

Comment: For the purposes of the question just assume it to be a number like 12.

Comment: @Phillip "a number like 12" doesn't specify the type of C or C++ language element that `startingLineNumber` ***is***.

Comment: Sorry for begin unclear. In my code there isn't any startingLineNumber.  It's a literal 12 written in it's place

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810889/c-preprocessor-output-int-at-build/69840388#69840388 answer your question? It's for DIV, but the mechanisms for substraction is the same. || Could please you create a full compilable [MCVE]?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [C Preprocessor output int at Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810889/c-preprocessor-output-int-at-build/69840388#69840388) first you have to implement operations:

```
typedef return_t (*f1)(params)
typedef return_t (*f2)(params)
void *GetProcAddress(charr *);

#define SUB_10_0   10
#define SUB_10_1   9
#define SUB_10_2   8
// etc. for each each possible combination, 1000 of lines ...
#define SUB_21_20  1
// etc. for each each possible combination, 1000 of lines ...
#define SUB_IN(a, b)  SUB_##a##_##b
#define SUB(a, b)  SUB_IN(a, b)


#define CONCAT_IN(a, b)  a##b
#define CONCAT(a, b)     CONCAT_IN(a, b)

#define startingLineNumber 20
#define GetFuncDef(glFunc) (CONCAT(f, SUB(__LINE__, startingLineNumber)))GetProcAddress(#glFunc)
int main() {
    f1 a = GetFuncDef();
}
```

Then `gcc -E` outputs:

```
typedef return_t (*f1)(params)
typedef return_t (*f2)(params)
void *GetProcAddress(charr *);
int main() {
    f1 a = (f1)GetProcAddress("");
}
```

In a similar fashion mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810889/c-preprocessor-output-int-at-build/69840388#69840388) Boost and P99 libraries can be used.