# Atomicity of the Increment Operator

Tags: c, language-lawyer, atomic

I was told in an interview that, in C, using the ++ operator (say i++) is an atomic operation while doing, say "i += 1" is not. I thought these operations were exactly the same when it comes to thread safety or atomicity. Am I missing something or are these actually different?

Comment: The interviewer is wrong - neither are guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: If a potential future boss told you that, I suggest you find another place of potential employment.

Comment: The compiler is likely to implement the expressions `++i` and `i += 1` very similarly (they're the same because the result of the expression is the incremented value).  This is different from `i++` where the result of the expression is the value before the increment.  As full statements, the three are equivalent.  None of them is guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: See also [In C, is `i += 1` atomic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790204/in-c-is-i-1-atomic)  It is not a duplicate because it doesn't mention `i++` or `++i`, but it is closely related.

Comment: This is a very good example of why C++ != C.  +1.on your question (be sure to give a -1 on your examiner.  Unless you need the job ;)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's nonsense. Either one may or may not be atomic, depending on the data type, the architecture, and perhaps the compiler (the standard doesn't make guarantees about atomicity in general unless you're using C11 atomics), but I can't see any good reason to think that, in general, `i++` would be atomic where `i += 1` isn't. It's very likely that they actually generate the same code, in a context where the result of the expression isn't used.

Answer (score 8):

The statements* `i++;` and `i += 1;` are equivalent in C. Neither is guaranteed to be atomic.

In particular, increments of variables larger than the system word size (e.g, 64-bit variables on 32-bit systems) are almost always non-atomic, as incrementing such a variable atomically would often require explicit locking. Additionally, some architectures do not support directly incrementing variables in memory. (That is, they require an explicit load/modify/store sequence.) These architectures cannot atomically modify *any* variable without locking.

<sub>* when considered as standalone statements, not expressions</sub>

Comment: further info: `++i` is defined as `i += 1`

Answer (score 2):

the interviewer is wrong.

I compiled two function with gcc-4.8.2 `-O2` `-S`

```
void increment1(int *a) {
  *a += 1;
}
void increment2(int *a) {
  (*a)++;
}
```

both generate exactly `the same` assembly

```
increment1:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        addl    $1, (%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   increment1, .-increment1
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  increment2
        .type   increment2, @function
increment2:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        addl    $1, (%rdi)
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

But in the context in more exact technical tarm, both of them are `atomic write` which means it does not provide **MAD** result.
if you use int64_t variable in 32 or less bit-wise CPU environment, 64bit-wise modification cause multiple write operation. It cannot be `atomic write` without lock.

You can use `__sync_fetch_and_add(&a, 1)` operation for atomic increment in gcc environment.

Comment: Just because these two functions generate identical x86 assembly using this version of GCC doesn't necessarily mean that they're **always** identical. Different compilers and architectures may behave differently. (You're correct here that they're identical, but only by accident.)