# Some really ugly C macro

Tags: c, macros

I need some really ugly C macro (as an example, not to any real project), that does some simple thing (like adding one, for example) really hard and unreadable way.

Anyone has some idea?

Comment: Is the http://www.ioccc.org/ site down?

Comment: Sorry.  I've trained myself over the years to write clear and understandable code.  Doing otherwise is now painful.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652788/what-is-the-worst-real-world-macros-pre-processor-abuse-youve-ever-come-across

Answer (score 3):

```
#define new delete
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#define True 0
#define False -1
```

Comment: `#define FileNotFound sqrt(False)`

Answer (score 1):

```
#define BEGIN {
```