# Macros to set and clear bits

Tags: c, embedded, macros, bit-manipulation

Im trying to write a few simple macros to simplify the task of setting and clearing bits which should be a simple task however I cant seem to get them to work correctly.

```
#define SET_BIT(p,n) ((p) |= (1 << (n)))
#define CLR_BIT(p,n) ((p) &= (~(1) << (n)))
```

Comment: It would help if you said how, exactly, the macros aren't working.

Comment: sorry about neglecting that... I thought the error would be obvious to some of the better versed c programmers here, rather than me *trying* to explain...

Comment: I could see two potential issues but without any context it's impossible to tell what applies to your situation and what doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
#define CLR_BIT(p,n) ((p) &= ~((1) << (n)))
```

However for various reasons of general macro evil I would advise not using a macro. Use an inline function and pass by reference, something like this:

```
static inline void set_bit(long *x, int bitNum) {
    *x |= (1L << bitNum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Iv heard all about the "evils" of macros and I generally restrict my use of them, but in this case Im just to the simplify the task of setting and clearing port pins on an AVR controller e.g CLR_BIT(PORTA, PIN3), I thought defines were acceptable in that context? but I guess  using inline functions would eliminate any headaches..

Comment: They're acceptable, there are certainly far worse ways to use the preprocessor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652788  but one day you'll have a strange bug that turns out to be macro-related.

Comment: True, Ive seen plenty of those horrors of macros threads.. Its scary how easily people can butcher the c language... I think Ill stick to inline functions when I can as long as they as are as fast as macros theres nothing to be lost only gained.

Comment: These *particular* macros are quite safe, since they evaluate each argument only once.

Comment: Agreed, they are pretty safe, but if you accidentally give them a pointer argument or some such, the errors will be more cryptic than usual. Macros with side effects are too easy to get wrong, though.

Comment: Does this work when sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)? I would have thought not, since 1 << bitNum would overflow.

Comment: Why should it be static?
I wrote myself a header with functions like this, I didn't use static but it worked like it should.

Answer (score 9):

One obvious issue is that `((p) &= (~(1) << (n)))` should be `((p) &= ~(1 << (n)))`.

Apart from that, you do have to be careful with the width of your integer types. If you were using `unsigned long` you might need to use (e.g.) `((p) |= (1UL << (n)))`

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  Do you not have a set of functions locally to do this for you?  That would hide any sort of magic that has to occur when skipping across word boundaries.

Failing that, how does the above fail?  They look 'ok', but I'd still rather do this sort of thing by hand if functions aren't available.  Macros just hide nasty bugs when doing this sort of thing.  Passing signed vs unsigned, etc.  Won't be caught with Macros.