# How can I assign bit by bit to an integer in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c)

I want to create an assembler , so I need to assign 32 bits bit by bit or field by field to create 32 bit opcode from assembly ... how can I do this in C ? how can I assign bits in integer ? can this be done ?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare these two macros to help you:

```
#define Set_Bit(IntValue, BitNumber) IntValue = IntValue | (1<<BitNumber)
#define Clr_Bit(IntValue, BitNumber) IntValue = IntValue & (~((1) << (BitNumber))))
```

Some questions have discussed these before:
[Macros to set and clear bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978408/macros-to-set-and-clear-bits)