# Preprocessor error when defining =

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was trying some awkward preprocessing and came up with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIX =6

int main(void)
{
  int x=6;
  int y=2;

  if(x=SIX)
    printf("X == 6\n");
  if(y=SIX)
    printf("Y==6\n");

  return 0;
}
```

gcc gives me the errors:

> test.c: In function ‘main’:
>       test.c:10:8: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token
>       test.c:12:8: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token

Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the worst real-world macros/pre-processor abuse you've ever come across?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652788/what-is-the-worst-real-world-macros-pre-processor-abuse-youve-ever-come-across)  Just kidding, good question.

Comment: Running this through the preprocessor, the tests turn into `if(x= =6)`.  I'm not sure why the space is inserted... presumably someone who knows one of the C specifications much better than me will come along...

Comment: The preprocessor deals in tokens, logically with spaces separating the tokens.  When it tokenizes `if(x=SIX)`, it has `if`, `(`, `x`, `=`, and `SIX`. When it macro expands `SIX`, it has extra tokens `=` and `6`.  But two adjacent tokens `=` are not the same as one token `==` (and are in fact invalid C syntax) — hence the compilation error.

Comment: Because the result of macro expansion is never rescanned for possible token pasting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `==` is a single token, it cannot be split in half. You should run `gcc -E` on your code

From GCC manual pages:

> `-E` Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.  The output is in 
>       the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output.
>
> Input files that don't require preprocessing are ignored.

For your code `gcc -E` gives the following output

```
  if(x= =6)
    printf("X == 6\n");

  if(y= =6)
    printf("Y==6\n");
```

The second `=` is what causes the error message `expected expression before ‘=’ token`

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor doesn't work at the character level, it operates at the token level. So when it performs the substitution, you get something equivalent to:

```
if (x = = 6)
```

rather than your desired:

```
if (x==6)
```

There are some specific exceptions to this, like the `#` stringification operator.

Comment: Where does the blank between `=` and `6` come from?

Comment: @alk I'm just using the spaces to show token boundaries. As far as the C grammar is concerned, there's no difference between `=6` and `= 6`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(x=SIX)
```

is parsed as

```
if (x= =6).
```

So you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

What toolchain are you using? If you are using GCC, you can add the `-save-temps` option and check the `test.i` intermediate result to troubleshoot your problem.

I suspect you have a space between the `x=` and the `=6`.