# Why does this practice code fail when length == 0?

Tags: c

Hi I have this book with a practice question which I am unable to answer. And no...this is not a homework question. This is my self study from a book recommended to me called: "Computer systems, A programmer's perspective"

Here is the question:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Compiling this with `gcc -Wextra` would generate a warning for the comparison between signed (`int i`) and unsigned (`unsigned length`).

Comment: Any reason you couldn't have just looked at the solution for this problem that the book provides for you?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart warnings? Who has extra byte for that? [Real russian do push-up on bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/652945/427309).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`length` is unsigned, so if you pass `0` for that parameter, `length - 1` will be `UINT_MAX`, not `-1` like you want it to be;  therefore the loop will run and you'll make acceses outside the size of `a`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - overflow of unsigned integers is totally well defined.

Comment: ohhhhhhhkay, I get it now! It wraps back around to all 1s. Thanks!, Sorry Im new these low level stuff :)

Comment: Overflow of signed integers is *undefined*, but not unsigned types.

Comment: Spec quotation: **6.2.5 Types** paragraph 9: "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."

Comment: It's worth mentioning that seeing `i <= length-1` is pretty uncommon. While changing `length` from an unsigned integer to a signed integer is one solution, much more often you'll simply see the loop condition expressed as `i < length` (which is equivalent). This is "better," because negative array lengths are not possible, and the length parameter really *should* be unsigned, since that gives you the maximum possible range for your data type.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `unsigned length to int length`  you code will run perfectly

while why the above code will not work is

when you use  unsigned length if you pass 0 to the length so in the loop you have `(length - 1)` which is cycles over the range and it takes the maximum value hence the loop gets segmentation fault