# Macro function to behave like for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, macros

Consider the following code i managed to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FOR(A, B, C) for(A; B; C++)

int main()
{
    FOR(i=0, i<10, i)
    printf("%i", i);

    return 1;
}
```

The output is:
`0123456789`

If i do `FOR(i=5, i<10, i)`
then respectively the output is `56789`

My questions are is that legal? Will it cause any errors in different cases? Does it works exactly like a for loop?

Comment: Why would you write macros like that?

Comment: 1. To use a common name for for loops instead of "for"

2. To save the writing of increment

3. To use the known function-form of parameters usage instead of for-form (using ; instead of commas)

Comment: If that's your requirement, just write a function to do looping.  You'll avoid the pit-falls of macros.

Comment: If i do function to do looping i will not be able to have a body of the for loop, which is a massive restriction.

Comment: This is exactly that kind of preprocessor abuse that parents warn their kids about. Don't try to reinvent C with preprocessor, you will end up in maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Edenia You could use a callback.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/652788/694733

Comment: @user694733 i would post this there if i knew it is that kind of "abuse" with preprocessor. For me.. it just more work for the preprocessor.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean?

Comment: @Edenia You could pass a function pointer into your standard for-loop function, the fp being a pointer to a custom function that's called to implement the job of the loop.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: @Ian oh with function pointers. I see. I have messed with that while working with signals before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's a "legal" macro, but no, it does not work like a real `for` loop.

Your macro won't handle this:

```
int a, b;
for(a = 0, b = 4711; a < b; ++a);
```

for instance, since you can't distinguish the `,` used to build a longer initializing expression to the one used to separate the expressions that make up the parts:

```
FOR(a = 0, b = 0, a < b, ++a);
```

will break, since it looks like a call with 4 arguments instead of 3.

Comment: Well.. for that i could use the concatenation directive.

Comment: You can use: FOR((a = 0, b = 0), a < b, ++a);

Comment: @didou True, but kind of defeats the point in my opinion. Of course, "the point" for something horrible like this is a bit hard to see from the beginning. :)

Comment: This example also shows why this cannot work at all (no matter how the macro is defined). The example given is ambiguous as a macro and could also mean `for(a = 0; b = 0, a < b; ++a)`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A macro is just copied everywhere the preprocessor sees you using the macro keyword.  It just copies the text, nothing more.

To elaborate on that a bit more, consider this example:

```
#define MY_MACRO a

int MY_MACRO = 5;
```

When the preprocessor comes along it will take the above and change it to:

```
int a = 5;
```

and then the compiler will come along and compile it like normal C/C++ code.

When you add arguments to your macro, they are just substituted in place within your macro.  This can be a problem, consider the following two macros:

```
#define BAD_MACRO(a, b) a*b
#define GOOD_MACRO(a, b) (a)*(b)
```

They look almost the same, but consider the following:

```
int k = BAD_MACRO(2, 3);    // k = 2*3 = 6
int j = GOOD_MACRO(2, 3);   // j = 2*3 = 6
int m = BAD_MACRO(2+1, 3);  // m = 2+1*3 = 5
int n = GOOD_MACRO(2+1, 3); // n = (2+1)*3 = 9
```

Although note that neither of these macros are good or bad, they just don't have the same behaviour as a typical function.

Comment: I fail to see how this is an answer to the question. Yes or no?

Comment: For me it looks like a decent lection of how macros work.
And i have learn that it is better `#define SUM(A, B) ((A)+(B))` yes. But anyway thats not what i asked for.

Comment: @unwind Yes, its legal; depends what you consider an error or a feature; and hmm, maybe but I don't think so...

Comment: Not quite what you asked for, but what I hoped you would find helpful. :)

Comment: I would really find it helpful. But i already know that.. so.