# Replace c++ macro's concatenation by modern c++ techniques

Tags: c++, c++11

I know it's better to avoid macros in c++. Use inline functions to replace function-like macros, and constexpr/using to replace const-variable-define macros.
But I would like to know if there is one way to replace macro concatenation functionality by some modern c++ techniques.

For example, how to replace the following macros:

```
#define GETTER_AND_SETTER(name)     \
   inline void Set##name(int value) \
   {                                \
      m_##name = value;             \
   }
   inline int Get##name() const     \
   {                                \
      return m_##name;              \
   }
```

then in a class, I can do this for a lot of variables, which makes the code more clean.

```
GETTER_AND_SETTER(Variable1)
GETTER_AND_SETTER(Variable2)
GETTER_AND_SETTER(Variable3)
...
```

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96196/when-are-c-macros-beneficial) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652788/what-is-the-worst-real-world-macros-pre-processor-abuse-youve-ever-come-across), but I don't get the answer. So any idea about this?

Edit:
The example of getters/setters is just used to show the idea. Please don't focus on them.

Comment: No, there is no way :)

Comment: Your problem is that you treat your class as a clump of data that needs getters & setters.

Comment: Creating new identifiers is still only possible with macros.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can't.**

There's no magic that you can perform with variable names at compile-time; C++ simply does not have any reflection capabilities. You may only *generate* code using the preprocessor to do the magic.

Typical workarounds involve `std::map`s of "names" to values, but your existing approach seems pretty reasonable to me unless you have a brazillion of the things.

Although, depending on your requirements, you might do better to forget about this "getter"/"setter" nonsense anyway, and just define some logical, semantic member functions for your class. If you're literally just creating a direct accessor and mutator for each member variable then, really, [what's the point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108025/560648)?

Comment: One of the points might be to find all places in code which exactly read or exactly write the data member. (You could only find where it's _accessed_ if you just read-write it directly.) This doesn't help with class' own methods though, which can access private data. This also hints that the class would just be an improved POD thing.

Comment: @Ruslan: Perhaps, but if you have more than one or two places of code writing to the same object, then your program is badly written and you don't have enough `const`. So it kind of becomes a moot point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's just an example to show the idea. :)